# Bitnami Rails Nginx Thin - The service is not available. Please try again later

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I'm trying to get a Bitnami Rails stack running with Nginx and 5 Thin app servers.

I have the Thin app servers running OK and I've got Nginx started and it's connected to the 5 Thin servers.

But, some code is giving me "The service is not available. Please try again later." html when I access my app from a browser.  I don't know where the code is that's giving me that message.

I have the Nginx server listening on port 80.

This is my nginx.conf file:  https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35302780/nginx.conf

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your config seems fine, except those 2 if statements because [IF is evil inside location block](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil). You may want to fix that.

Seems that you are using a [3rd party upstream module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamFairModule). Try to uninstall that module and use the normal upstream module.